# Embed characters for Europe and America

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, embed, typeface

I'm developing an app in Flash AS3 for a target audience in Europe and America. 
So now I need to embed the characters for the photo caption text field. 
There are "Basic Latin", "Latin Extended A", "Latin Extended B", "Latin Extended Add'l" and other sets available.

Are there some informations on which characters are really necessary or do I need to embed all sets? (There is an option to pick just some characters of them)

Thanks for any feedback on this.
Steven

Answer (score 4):

I am a flash developer from Spain and we run into this kind of problem all the time. Try no to embed all sets of characters, because the weight of your flash movie will increase a lot!

In my company's blog we have set up a blog post with all the characters you need for most of Europe's languages (it covers Spanish and Portuguese so for America it should be useful too). In fact, it's more a list of characters ready to COPY/PASTE than a real blog post, and it saves us a lot of time!

It's in Spanish, but hopefully it will be useful for you as well (just ignore the text and scroll down to the lists of characters):
http://www.lostiemposcambian.com/blog/flash/embeber-caracteres-especiales-idiomas-en-flash/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no direct correlation between the Unicode character sets and real world languages (though there is a rough correlation.) Basic Latin and Latin Extended A should take care of English, German and most other European languages (Spanish, French.)

Latin Extended B supports "195 glyphs supporting a good mix of languages from Romania to Africa, via Runic." (From: http://design.canonical.com/2010/10/the-weird-and-wonderful-world-of-latin-extended-b/) and can probably be safely ignored as can Latin Extended Add'l. However, you should check how much size those extra character sets add (when you build, do a size report. The size required for characters will be called out as a line item.) Is the extra character support worth the extra size? That's up to you and your business needs.